# Lookup + match 2 cells against another sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to compare two cells (in two diff columns) next to each other i.e. A2&B2, against a list in another sheet which will have the main data again in two columns next to each other.

I want to compare the cells A:A&B:B against the main list for matches and for it to tell me yes/no whether it found a match.

I've tried the following:

```
=INDEX('REDIRECT MAP'!A:B,MATCH(A2&B2,'REDIRECT MAP'!A:A&'REDIRECT MAP'!B:B,0))
```

However this just returns the same two cells from the main list (if they're present / the condition finds a match) - whereas I'd like to coerce it to a boolean so that it returns Yes/No statement if it does/doesn't find a match (which im unable to do atm).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2&B2,'REDIRECT MAP'!A:A&'REDIRECT MAP'!B:B,0)), "No", "Yes"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of these might simplify matters.

```
'for boolean value of TRUE/FALSE
 =and(countifs('REDIRECT MAP'!A:A, A2, 'REDIRECT MAP'!B:B, B2))
'for string value of yes/no
 =if(countifs('REDIRECT MAP'!A:A, A2, 'REDIRECT MAP'!B:B, B2), "yes", "no")
```